# Difficulty Understanding manner of callbacks in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a solution to a exercise from nodeschool.io's adventure-stream course.

I am having difficulty understanding how the line works

```
req.pipe(upper).pipe(res)
```

A deep explanation of what happens internally would be greatly appreciated.

To my understanding the request sends its information to upper to be transformed, but when it returns via the callback, is the second pipe called on the return value?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var through2 = require('through2');

var upper = through2(function(data, _, next) {
   data = data.toString().toUpperCase();
   next(null,data);
});


http.createServer(function(req,res) {
   if (req.method == 'POST') {
      req.pipe(upper).pipe(res);
   }
}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pipe` is sugar over what's more or less

```
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    next_stream.write(chunk);
});

// also handle the 'end' and 'close' events
```

And returns `next_stream`, so `.pipe`s can be chained. `res` is a writable stream that represents the stream read by the browser, which simply needs to be written to and closed for a response to make it to the browser, which `.pipe` does.

I guess it's worth nothing that there's not really a "callback" that is called to "finish" the response in this case. The browser simply gets data as we write it to `res` and stops loading more data when `res` is closed.

Check out the NodeJS source code for [the `.pipe` method](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L48)